# SSRS Chart Column Titles Missing

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I'm currently working on a report to display the number of consented patients by disease group and my column titles aren't displaying for every column. For whatever reason, they are alternating thus only displaying half of the column titles. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Here is a picture of the chart as it's displaying now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the axis interval to 1.

TechNet: [How to: Specify an Axis Interval](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239317.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your answer and link were dead on!